# Google Sheet Apps Script - Change Cell Data and Increment One Row Down

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to.. 1) replace a substring from the contents of the active cell in my sheet, and.. 2) move the active cell down one spot, and repeat until the active cell value is empty. Here's my function, but nothing happens when I run it...can anyone see why?

```
  var app = SpreadsheetApp;            
  var mySheet = ss.getSheetByName('NAME');
  var activeCell = mySheet.getActiveCell();
  var cellValue = activeCell.getValue();
  var activeRow = activeCell.getRow();

  function replaceStringInCell(){
     while(cellValue != ''){
       var newCellValue = cellValue.replace('MC/Visa/Discover', 'CC');
       activeCell.setValue(newCellValue); 
       activeRow++;
       mySheet.getRange(activeRow, 7).activate();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you...I tried adding the SpreadsheetApp.flush(), and this made the cell move down consistently, but only the first cell had its content modified. It's as if the loop can only execute one command maximum..

Comment: It's  because the active cell isn't changed in the loop and only refers to the initial cell. Do you really want visual feedback?- Why can't you just change all of the column in one batch?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean by that. Could you provide an example?

Comment: Yes, that would work, but I'm just replacing a substring in each cell if it's contained therein.

Answer (score 1):

#### Issue:

- Unnecessary looping over each cell

#### Solution:

- Use batch operations

#### Sample Script:

```
 function replaceColA() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var mySheet = ss.getSheetByName('NAME');
  var cellRange = mySheet.getRange('A1:A' + mySheet.getLastRow());
  var cellValues = cellRange.getValues().map(replaceStringInCell); //call replace function on all values in range
  cellRange.setValues(cellValues); //set mapped values back to range 
}
function replaceStringInCell(cellValue) {
  if (cellValue.map) {
    //if cellValue is a array
    return cellValue.map(replaceStringInCell); //recurse
  } else {
    return cellValue.replace('MC/Visa/Discover', 'CC');
  }
}
```

#### To Read:

- [Arrays](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp)
- [Array#Methods](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_array_methods.asp)
- [Array#2DFromSpreadsheets](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/reading#read_a_single_range)
- [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [String#replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)